# Coloring binary tree edges with given number of colors

Tags: graph-theory, trees, coloring

Let's say I have a balanced binary tree which has 37 leaves.
I can color the vertices of this tree with 37 colors.
$$ 37 * 36^{72} $$ ways.
How can I find out coloring edges with 37 colors?

---

Original problem is,
1. Let T be a binary tree with 37 leaves.

(b) In how many ways can you color T using 37 colors?
I think the answer for this problem is $$ 37 * 36^{72} $$
I assumed that this value is calculating vertices not edges. So I wondered, how many ways can I color edges of T using 37 colors.

Comment: Can you please add a little more explanation?

Comment: @AnkitKumarI did.

Comment: What does "To color its vertices differently" mean?

Comment: @AnkitKumar I edited

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still unable to understand what it means. If possible, can you tell me where you found this question? Or post a pic of the same?

Comment: @AnkitKumar can you understand better?

Comment: Yes! It's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've written $37*36^{72}$, I assume you figured out that it has $73$ vertices. Further, no restriction of any kind is given. So, its more of a problem (and a pretty simple one to be honest) on combinatorics and not graph theory.

1. Coloring vertices- $73$ vertices, each can choose from $37$ colors $\implies 37^{73}$ ways!
2. Coloring edges- $73$ vertices $\implies 72$ edges, each can choose from $37$ colors $\implies 37^{72}$ ways!